# How to find the probability of a certain number of runs in a string of coin flips?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I have a hw question that asks:

Consider randomly chosen strings of length 10 constructed from the alphabet {a,b} where each string is equally likely to be chosen.

What is the probability s will contain strictly more than 3 runs?

For reference on what I do know how to do, I know how to find out the probability of a certain number of heads or tails in a given amount of flips. This question though has been giving me a really hard time.

Mainly, how do I find out the possible configurations of a's and b's for each different run count? If I can figure this out I probably can figure the rest out. I understand what my sample space is already, and I understand that my answer will be 1-p(X1) + p(X2) + p(X3) where each X is the number of runs. I can provide any other info if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of runs depend on how many times we change from a to b. Thus, instead of looking at the string as 10 letters, look at it as the first letter, a or b, and nine bits, where the $i^{\text{th}}$ bit is 1 if and only if the $i^{\text{th}}$ letter in the string is not the same as the $(i+1)^{\text{th}}$ letter. For example:
$$abbbbaaabb=(a,100010010)$$
Since the string changes letters from the first to second, fifth to sixth, and eighth to ninth letters, we have set the first, fifth, and eighth bits to 1 and all the rest to 0.

Now, we can ignore the first letter since that has nothing to do with the number of runs. A new run is created when we encounter a 1 bit. Thus, what is the probability that a nine-bit number has at least two ones? If we look at this probability as the complement of the probability that a nine-bit number has either zero or one ones, the problem becomes quite simple:

- Probability that nine-bit nnumber has zero ones: $\frac{_9 C _0}{2^9}$
- Probability that nine-bit number has one ones: $\frac{_9 C _1}{2^9}$
- Probability that nine-bit number has at least two ones: $$1-\frac{_9 C _0}{2^9}-\frac{_9 C _1}{2^9}=\frac{502}{512}=\frac{251}{256}$$